# How do i choose the reference point correctly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image]

Hello in my engineering physics one course, I have come across several circumstances in which I will have to choose a point from which I have to consider the motion of a rigid body but The thing is I get confused as to which reference point to take oftentimes. In the image I have attached for example when my professor solved the question given the force which is indicated by F that is acted upon towards the negative $x$-axis is 0 at the time the call to $T =0$. He then chose the point P in order to determine the angular acceleration for the disk my question is not only for this particular example but in general what should I keep in mind when I try to choose a reference point for the motion of the rigid body I'm concerned with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every point of reference is valid so no point is more "correct" than another. It comes down to practicality: for some points of reference the math is a whole lot easier than for others.

For rigid homogenous objects that's typically the center of gravity (which conveniently happens to be geometric enter as well).

But every problem is different and finding the right reference point(s) and co-ordinate systems helps a lot to minimize the work required to solve the problem. There isn't a "one-size-fits-all" rule. If it's not obvious, you can try a few different ones and see which one is the easiest to deal with.

Comment: But for the sake of making my math easier if i chose say for example a reference point that nulls a torque part(rotation aspect) of the system, wouldn't that be a misrepresentation of the system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are balancing moments or torques, try to choose a reference point (i.e. axis of rotation) that the most forces are acting on, because it will allow you to reduce the number of terms in your moment balance

Answer (score 0):

The is a point of Physics in your question which should be addressed.

You ask why point $P$?
Well in terms of this particular example you state *in order to determine the angular acceleration for the disk* by using $\tau = I \alpha$, but his choice of point $P$ was also on the assumption that point $P$ was not moving (not accelerating) and so defined an inertial frame.
Using this criteria point $Q$ could also have been used as it was not accelerating.
In this example point $C$, which I assume is the centre of mass of the disc, is also one which can be used but it could also be used even if the centre of mass was accelerating, ie defined a non-inertial frame, because any pseudo forces which need to be introduced will act through the the centre of mass and not contribute a torque about $C$.

Here is a simple example.
A uniform rod $AB$ of length $2\,\rm m$ with centre of mass $C$
is acted on by two forces as shown in the diagram.

[image]

The moment of inertia of the rod is the same about $A$ and $B$ but the torque is not, so $\tau = I \alpha$ is not working and that is because points $A$ and $B$ define non-inertial frames.
Adding a pseudo force of $1\,\rm N$ upwards at the centre of mass resolves the problem and note that the rod is now acted on by a couple of $2\rm\,Nm$.